# WebAPI return KeyValue list for select box

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want a WebApi controller to return a Dictionary (keyvalue pairs) for a drop down box.  This is using angularjs $http.get() method.  When I get the data back to my controller and inspect the javascript, it appears I'm getting an Object with properties that are named like my keys in the Dictionary.  This does not work and the dropdown remains empty.

JavaScript result from $http.get()

```
Object
test1: "test 1"
test2: "test 2"
```

WebAPI code:

```
[HttpGet]
public Dictionary<string, string> Get()
{
    return new Dictionary<string, string>(){
        { "test1", "test 1"},
        { "test2", "test 2"}
    };
```

Code in my view:

```
<select name="originType" class="form-control"
        ng-model="OriginType"
        ng-options="type.Key as type.Value for type in values">
</select>
```

And my controller:

```
    $http.get('/api/mycontroller');
        .success(function (values) {
            $scope.values= values;
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in values"`. I think the problem is that you are attempting to use both the key and value of an object, whilst trying to reference, `.Key` & `.Value`, which don't actually exist.

If you wanted to do your `ng-options` your original way, your returned object should look like:

```
var result = [
    { Key: 'test1', Value: 'test1Value' },
    { Key: 'test2', Value: 'test2Value' }
]
```

To return the object from WebAPI like this the method should look like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Get()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>(){
            { "test1", "test 1"},
            { "test2", "test 2"}
        }.ToList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    }
```

Comment: I would like my results to be returned that way.  I'm not sure why a dictionary (which is just a list of keyvalue pairs) is not being returned that way from WebAPI.

Comment: I'm going to give you credit for the answer and add what I did to get the WebAPI controller to return data as a key value pair that would work with my angularjs code.